# Dice Rolling in BlueJ

Tags: bluej, dice

What is wrong with my code? I'm using **BlueJ**. Basically what I'm trying to do is, choose how many sides the dice has, input the number of each of the sides, roll the dice a certain number of times and show how much times a number has been rolled.

Example: Six sides, numbers are: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6. I roll the dice 20 times. And I see how many times a side had been rolled.

**Error is java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException**

```
import javax.swing.*;
class Dice
{
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
            int c = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How many sides?"));
            String[ ] number = new String[c];
            int[ ] sides = new int[c];

            int d = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How many times do you want to roll your dice?"));
            int[ ] output = new int[c];

            for(int i=0;i<c;i++)
            {
                number[i] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter side number:");
            }
            for(int i=0;i<d;i++)
            {
                int r;
                r = (int) Math.floor(Math.random() * c) + 1;

                if(r == sides[i])
                {
                    sides[i] = sides[i] + 1;
                }
            }
            for(int i=0;i<c;i++)
            {
                System.out.println(number[i] + " was rolled " + output[i] + " times.");
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: You tell us what's wrong! Add an exception message if any, and also the expected and actual output.

Answer (score 1):

Your line of code which reads

```
int[ ] output = new int[c]
```

should actually read

```
int[ ] output = new int[d]
```

because the size of your output array should be equal to the number of times the user wants to roll the die which is stored in d.  c stores the number of sides on the die.

Answer (score -1):

```
import javax.swing.*;
class Dice
{
public static void main (String [] args)
{
        int c = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How many sides?"));
        String[ ] number = new String[c];


        int d = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How many times do you 
     want to roll your dice?"));
        int[ ] output = new int[c];

        for(int i=0;i<c;i++)
        {
            number[i] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter side number:");
        }
        for(int i=0;i<d;i++)
        {
            System.out.println("exoashf");
            int r;
            r = (int) Math.floor(Math.random() * c) + 1;
            for(int j=0;j<d;i++)
            {
                int n1=Integer.parseInt(number[j]);
                if(r==n1)
                {
                    output[j]=output[j]+1;
                }
            }
        }
        for(int i=0;i<c;i++)
        {
            System.out.println("number, "+number[i]+"was rolled "+output[i]+"times");
        }
    }
   }
```

Comment: there is something wrong with ur code. its showing wrong output. try this code!!!!

Comment: Can you explain your answer?
This might help you out https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer.